# Daily Hour Picker Like Breather

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

[image: Breather]

I want to add something to my app like this image above, from Breather, where I can choose a time range by dragging the two circles around. I don't know what this is called exactly and was wondering if there was a way to do it in Swift or if there is a Cocoapod for something like this. Haven't started on it yet, so don't have any code. If anyone has experience with this kind of stuff, I'd love to know!

Comment: what you have tried yet???

Comment: As i said, I haven't started on this yet except looking for a library, but haven't been able to find anything yet.